# Read string array passed on pages navigation

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently not sure how I should read the parameters when I get a string passed from another page in WP8.1. This is actually the code I use to pass the parameter while navigating to the other page:

```
String[] parameters = new String[3];
parameters[0] = ReliabilitySwitch.IsEnabled.ToString();
if (i != 2)
{
    parameters[1] = UnitsList.SelectedItem.ToString();
    parameters[2] = MethodSwitch.IsEnabled.ToString();
}
else
{
    parameters[1] = "2";
}    
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Nav),parameters);
```

This said, I am not sure how I should read from the other page the parameters I am passing. I know how I could read, for instance, an integer value. I have tried reading this parameter like this, but I am surely missing some data during the process:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    String parameters;
    parameters = e.Parameter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: [I've removed tags from question's title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). I've also added more appropriate one in 'Tags'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`e.parameter` is of type `object`. Just cast it back to its original type:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    String[] parameters = (String[])e.Parameter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone:

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View.xaml?QueryStringParameter=myValue", UriKind.Relative));

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    String parameter = NavigationContext.QueryString["QueryStringParameter"];

    // OR

    string param;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue(
        "QueryStringParameter", out param)
    {
        // a parameter exists. work with the value
    }

}
```

Comment: Notice the `Frame.Navigate`. He's using WinRT, not Silverlight.

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice it while writing my answer.